# Code for writing and reading on a device file from a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, kernel-module

I have tried the following code many times .

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/cdev.h>
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/semaphore.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("DUAL BSD/GPL");
static int dev_open(struct inode *,struct file *);
static int dev_release(struct inode *,struct file *);
ssize_t dev_read(struct file *,char *, size_t ,loff_t *);
ssize_t dev_write(struct file *,const char *,size_t ,loff_t *);

static int major;
int dev_major = 0;
int dev_minor = 0;
struct cdev *cdev;

struct device {
    char array[100];
    struct semaphore sem;
}chr_arr;

struct file_operations dev_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = dev_read,
    .write = dev_write,
    .open = dev_open,
    .release = dev_release
};

ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offset)
{
    int i;
    i=copy_to_user(buf,chr_arr.array,count);
    printk(KERN_ALERT"buff:%s",buf);
    return i;
}

ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp,const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offset)
{
    //printk(KERN_ALERT"\nsorry,byebye");
    int j;
    //msg_ptr = kmalloc(count,GFP_KERNEL);
    //for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    if(count>100)
        return -1;
    j = copy_from_user(chr_arr.array,buf,count);
    //printk(KERN_ALERT"msg_ptr:%s",msg_ptr);
    return j;
}

static int dev_open(struct inode *inode,struct file *filp)
{
    filp->private_data = inode->i_cdev;
    if(down_interruptible(&chr_arr.sem))
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO " could not hold semaphore");
        return -1;
    }
    //printk(KERN_ALERT"ah ha the device is open !now we can go further");
    return 0;
}

static int dev_release(struct inode *inode,struct file *filp)
{
    up(&chr_arr.sem);
    //module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    return 0;
}

static int init_device(void)
{
    int result;
    dev_t dev_no,dev;
    result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_no,0,1,"chr_dev");
    if(result < 0)
    {
        printk("sorry no major number left");
        return result;
    }
    major = MAJOR(dev_no);
    dev = MKDEV(major,0);
    cdev = cdev_alloc();
    cdev->ops = &dev_ops;
    sema_init(&chr_arr.sem,1);
    printk("the major number allocated is %d\n",major);
    result = cdev_add(cdev,dev,1);
    if(result < 0 )
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to allocate cdev");
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void clean_device(void)
{
    cdev_del(cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(major,1);
}

module_init(init_device);
module_exit(clean_device);
```

but its giving me the following warning.

```
CC [M]  /home/karan/practice/scrw/scrw1.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-2.6.34.10-0.6/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:571:0,
             from /home/karan/practice/scrw/scrw1.c:4:
In function ‘copy_from_user’,inlined from ‘write’ at /home/karan/practice/scrw/scrw1.c:43:6:
/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.10-0.6/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h:212:26: warning: call to ‘copy_from_user_overflow’ declared with attribute warning: copy_from_user() buffer size is not provably correct
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC      /home/karan/practice/scrw/scrw1.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/karan/practice/scrw/scrw1.ko
```

and then when I try to write echo hi > /dev/my_dev the screen freezes after 30 secs or so.

Comment: shouldn't you test for count < 100?

Comment: @ypnos         thats ok but its not working whenever i put echo command it hangs after few secs....

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere else. Can you show more of your code? You can also try to recompile your kernel with debugging options enabled, that way you might get a stack trace when the freeze occurs.

Comment: @ldx    hi ... could you tell how to give you my code ...i dont think its possible to write code on comment....

Comment: @ldx           hi you could see my code on the following forum's link under karan2386 user id (latest) [link] http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-write-on-a-device-file-using-copy_from_user-925762/

Comment: Can't you edit your original question? You can also upload it to e.g. pastebin.

Comment: @idx           hi ... i have done it could you have a look at it.

Comment: @ldx           now write function is working fine but the read function is not ...whenever i use cat /dev/my_dev it reads infintely i have tried with return count an dwithout it also.....please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you should return the number of bytes read/written in your read/write methods, the return value of copy_{from,to}_user() is 0 if everything goes well. Return e.g. count in your write method if copying succeeds:

```
unsigned long ret;
printk(KERN_INFO "Inside write \n");
if (count > sizeof(char_arr.array) - 1)
    return -EINVAL;
ret = copy_from_user(char_arr.array, buff, count);
if (ret)
    return -EFAULT;
char_arr.array[count] = '\0';
return count;
```

You should also make sure that a terminating '\0' character is appended when you copy to your buffer (if you'd like to deal only with strings). If it is binary data you deal with store its length in your struct as well.

An example read method:

```
ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offset)
{
    int len = count >= strlen(chr_arr.array) ? strlen(chr_arr.array) : count;

    if (*offset >= strlen(chr_arr.array))
        return 0;

    if (copy_to_user(buf,chr_arr.array,len))
        return -EFAULT;

    return len;
}
```

Edit: messed up example code, fixing it.

Edit2: example read method.

Comment: now write function is working fine but the read function is not ...whenever i use cat /dev/my_dev it reads infintely i have tried with return count an dwithout it also.....please help

Comment: That's because you should return 0 once the user gets to the end of your device. You can use offset to store current position.

Comment: i think when any user writes hi(echo hi > /dev/my_dev) in the device file it wont go to the end of the device file(please correct me if i am wrong)....and how can i use offset could you show me in codes....really thank you for you enthusiasm and interest...